# Will it ever be possible to port BlackBerry messenger (BBM) to the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, applications, messages, chat

Will we ever have BBM service on the iPhone ? Is it possible to port such feature from the blackberry to the iPhone ? I know they use their own servers for verification, but isn't there a method that can divert users to such servers from a stand-alone app made on the iPhone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost certainly *technically* possible, but the reason it hasn't been done isn't a technical one, it's a business one.

BBM and the network of users that go with it is one of RIM's strategic assets, and their thinking is likely that opening it up on other platforms would eliminate a reason for people to buy their hardware (which is where they make their money). Whether that's a sound decision or not and whether RIM may change its mind may be up for debate, but at the moment, that's why there's no BBM for iOS, Android or any non-Blackberry platform, not technical challenges.

Comment: Why won't anyone do an app then ?? A Cydia app or something ? Would take a while before apple manages to take it down if its via Cydia ..

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more clear. It's possible for *RIM* to make such an app, not a 3rd party developer. BBM is tightly integrated into RIM's servers, and they don't provide external access (for the reasons outlined in the answer).

Comment: Oh okay makes sense .. So trying to access such servers externally would be illegal right ?